# Pass Array As Parameter Into A Stored Function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I wan to pass Array as parameter into a stored a stored function Postgresql,
I wan to pass Employee Names as a parameter and get the ID of employee using select query pass it as a input to the delete query.

select * from links;

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(first_name varchar(255))
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  emp_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
 SELECT id into emp_id from links e where name = first_name;
 DELETE FROM links WHERE id = emp_id;
 return emp_id;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

select * from testing('Google');

I could able to delete single record from table.
now i want to pass as a parameter into my function to delete records.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as input (type `text[]`).

Then the whole operation becomes a single statement:

```
DELETE FROM links
WHERE name = ANY ($1)
RETURNING id;
```

Here, `$1` is the placeholder for the array.

Comment: can you please give me an simple example using my above function.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434482/issue-while-passing-arrays-to-stored-function