# Issue while passing arrays to stored Function

Tags: postgresql, function

trying to delete records by passing arrays into the stored function.

```
testing=# select * from links;
 id |                url                 |        name         | description | last_update
----+------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------
  1 | https://www.postgresqltutorial.com | PostgreSQL Tutorial |             |
  2 | http://www.oreilly.com             | O'Reilly Media      |             |
  7 | http://www.postgresql.org          | PostgreSQL          |             |
  8 | https://www.google.com             | Google              |             | 2013-06-01
(4 rows)
```

My Function

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(TEXT[])
        RETURNS INTEGER AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE emp_id INTEGER;
        BEGIN
         SELECT id into emp_id from links e where name = ANY($1);
         DELETE FROM links WHERE id = emp_id;
         return emp_id;
        END
        $BODY$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Query to call function

```
SELECT * from testing(ARRAY['PostgreSQL','Google']::TEXT[]);
```

We pass two records to delete from the links table, But instead of that only one record is deleting.

```
    testing=# select * from links;
 id |                url                 |        name         | description | last_update
----+------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------
  1 | https://www.postgresqltutorial.com | PostgreSQL Tutorial |             |
  2 | http://www.oreilly.com             | O'Reilly Media      |             |
  7 | http://www.postgresql.org          | PostgreSQL          |             |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Laurenz already answered that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71406104/

Comment: I tried the same but i am not able to delete multiple records passing arrays.

Comment: Well, you need to follow Laurenz' answer completely. Get rid of your SELECT it's not needed

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... INTO` only stores the first row in the variable and ignores the rest.

You should declare the function as `RETURNS SETOF integer`, omit the `SELECT` and run only the `DELETE` as detailed in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71406104/6464308). Then you can use an SQL function rather than a PL/pgSQL one, which will simplify everything.